# Dynamic reading of satellite DLL without changing GUI using MFC

Tags: mfc

So I have a MFC application which has language resources in several satellite DLL files.

When the program starts it loads the correct DLL and sets it for the application resources.

My question, is it possible to read, say a STRINGTABLE entry from a DLL without setting it as a GUI? For example, I am running the application in ITALIAN, but for reasons I want to allow the show to show some information in SPANISH.

Can we access the STRINGTABLE of a satellite DLL without setting it as the application GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 
[`CString::LoadString(HINSTANCE hInstance, UINT nID)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2017#loadstring) or 
`CString::LoadString(HINSTANCE hInstance, UINT nID, WORD wLanguageID)`.

Example:

```
HINSTANCE hinst = LoadLibrary(L"path.dll");

CString str;
if (str.LoadString(hinst, ID_STRING100))
    AfxMessageBox(str);
```

You can also call `AfxSetResourceHandle(hinst)` and simply follow up with `str.LoadString(ID_STRING100)`. Example:

```
AfxSetResourceHandle(hinst);
str.LoadString(ID_STRING100);
...

//reset resource handle:
AfxSetResourceHandle(AfxGetInstanceHandle());
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I use AfxSet... won’t it then change the GUI interface momentarily? I will try your first suggestion.

Comment: I am trying to find the MSDN reference for this. I can see LoadString which accepts a HINSTANCE but it seems to be a Win32 API call and not the CString derivative.

Comment: I added link. If using `AfxSetResourceHandle` you must reset the handle when before looking at own dll.

Comment: I notice that `LoadString` takes a `HINSTANCE` but `LoadLibrary` returns a `HMODULE`. It seems to work so thank you. I might have another question for  clarification about this but need to test first.

Comment: HINSTANCE and HMODULE are the same thing. Many, many, many years ago, in a galaxy far away, they were different. But, they are now the same. Raymond Chen: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903

Comment: Thanks. My related query ... if the users default language in the app is non English and we now want to partially show English resources can I pass the executable path to loadlubrary? Because if I just use loadstring it would give the active localised value and not exe value. Note that I would not want to change the active language of gui. It is only the comments of interest. This making sense.

Comment: Use `AfxGetInstanceHandle()` to get `HINSTANCE` for your main GUI process. I am not sure which method you are using, maybe you can edit your question and show.